# How to find colors that clash?

Tags: color

I try to learn more about colors and color theory. So far I have learned how to create a pallet of colors that match. But I could not find any information on clashing colors.

The only thing I was able to find was fashion related advice. But that was more like "do not mix pink and orange" and did not sound very scientific.

My guess is that two colors do clash if they have a similar (but different) hue and very different saturation and luminance.

Is there any theory on this? How can I find colors that really hurt the eye?

Comment: all colors can match or mismatch depend on your artwork. and every color mixing have a plan and Artistic point of view .. for example writing with green over blue ... this will be hard to read .. but it could be a perfect background for a tennis player for example. not to distort the vision of the other play ... and so one.

Answer (score 3):

There is plenty of theory on this. Complementary colors are pleasing (for example). Go to [color.adobe.com](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/) and play with the color wheel.

Find the rules (which are based on theory) and then break them.  It might not be the answer you're looking for - but the search has been to find combinations that work.

All the articles I've read have paragraphs here and there discussing why colors don't work together but the goal of the articles were to explain what works.